# How To Use Spec with Namespace Keywords That Aren't Valid Namespaces Coming From Datomic?

Tags: clojure, datomic, clojure.spec

I'm not sure how to word my question, so apologies if it's confusing. I'm currently trying to write specs for some data that's coming out of datomic. A map I'm getting back might look like:

```
{:id "123abc" :event/date "1/1/2020"}
```

My goal is to write a spec like:

```
(s/def ::result (s/keys :req-un [::id string? :event-date string?]))
```

I've tried a couple things, and have setup a namespace `schema.event` where I'm defining the spec for date.

```
(ns schema.event)
(s/def :event/date string?)
```

The issue is that none of these work, I can't seem to get it to work with data containing `event/date` as it keeps validating on just `:date`.

The following will return success with my current setup:

```
{:id "123abc" :date "1/1/2020"}
```

But that doesn't mirror the data I'm getting from Datomic so isn't very helpful. What am I doing wrong here? I suspect it's just something to do with my lack of understand on how Clojure is treating namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using the `:req-un` option. Try switching to the `:req` one. And you can have both - `:req-un` for `::id` and `:req` for `:event/date`.